# Why is this structure declaration allowed in a built-in Function Module but not in a new one?

Tags: abap, function-module

I'm working on a Function Module to assist with dealing with included text with logic embedded. While looking into the way SAP handles SAPScript files and parses the logic I found a structure that is declared as so:

```
DATA BEGIN OF events OCCURS 100.
      INCLUDE STRUCTURE ITCCA.
DATA: command LIKE BOOLEAN,
      template LIKE BOOLEAN,
      mask LIKE BOOLEAN,
     END OF events.
```

This obviously works, as I can trace through it while it is running a print program. So I thought I would try a similar structure in my own code but even when I copied the code 1 for 1 like above I get an error during activation. The error is

```
"BOOLEAN" must be a flat structure. Internal tables, references, 
strings and structures are forbidden as components.
```

Can someone explain to me why this structure is valid in one program and not mine?

Comment: Where did you find the original code?

Comment: It is a part of the `STXC` Function Group. I did find some information about this after I posted this question. It seems that with `LIKE` I would have to define the `BOOLEAN` type myself but if I used `TYPE` then it would use the dictionary value for `BOOLEAN`. Not sure why they decided to define it themselves in their original code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain the actual effect: `LIKE` usually refers to a **data object** (an actual variable) on the right-hand side, **not a data type**. As you rightly discovered, once you provide a **data object** named `BOOLEAN`, that is used to construct the type. If a data object of that name is not present and you're not within a class or an interface, an [obsolete variant of the `LIKE` statement](https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abenlike_obsolete.htm) will be triggered that also takes data types into account, but only allows for certain elements on the right-hand side - namely only flat structured objects or their components. `LIKE DATATYPE-BOOLEAN` should have worked. As usual, the error message is somewhat less than helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. As a newcomer to SAP and ABAP I'm finding lots of little gotchas in understanding how it all works.

Comment: Learn to live with it - that feeling won't go away any time soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems during my initial investigation I missed a declaration for the `BOOLEAN` type. In the `STXC` function group SAP decided to declare their own variable for boolean in a different include file like this:

```
data: boolean(1) type c.
```

I had originally assumed that they were doing this with the dictionary defined type which has a similar name and is a 1 character long string. What I also found is that if I were to change my structure declaration like this:

```
DATA BEGIN OF events OCCURS 100.
  INCLUDE STRUCTURE ITCCA.
DATA: command TYPE BOOLEAN,
  template TYPE BOOLEAN,
  mask TYPE BOOLEAN,
 END OF events.
```

My code would be valid because it would then be using the dictionary defined value. So either I have to add a declaration for my own definition of `boolean` so that I can use the `LIKE` keyword or I have to use the `TYPE` keyword to use the dictionary definition.